# Write data from text box to a text file

Tags: php

I have developed a text box and I am trying to write this data to a text file.
The PHP code is generating the file but the data is not being written.
below is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form" method="post">
<input type="text" name="text_box" size="50"/>
<input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="submit" />
<?
$a=@$_POST["text_box"];
$myFile = "t.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh,$a);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form's submit action is "get", but in your PHP code, you get the variable by $_POST. Try by $_GET instead.

Answer (score 3):

the biggest issue i see with your code is the fact that you aren't opening php tags. you do

```
<?
```

but it should be

```
<?php
```

then, the way you call $_POST and write file and stuff means it will be executed when you first load the form into the browser as well. the php engine makes no distinction between first run and consecutive run. this means that even if the user don't submit anything, there will still be an empty file, created from the run of the script where the form was displayed. it's a side effect. i've modified your code just a little. here's my take on this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="form" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="text_box" size="50"/>
            <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['text_box'])) { //only do file operations when appropriate
        $a = $_POST['text_box'];
        $myFile = "t.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, $a);
        fclose($fh);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I Used the above code, it still doesn't do anything and moreover even the file t.txt is not created

Comment: @Pink very strange. that code works in my wamp on a 32  bit windows xp. what's your setup? sounds like maybe there's a file permission error..

Comment: I am not using wamp or xampp and running this scripts on 64 bit windows 7. I have no clue with file permissions

Comment: did you create a new directory under your www folder, and then **copy/paste** my code into that document, and run it without further modifications? if not, try that. also, what web server are you running? is it apache? and what version of php have you installed?

Comment: @Pink i forgot to notify you in my last message.

Comment: @Pink also, i meant "did you create a new directory under your www folder, **add a new file called index.php**, and then copy/paste my code into that document".

Comment: Thanks a lot, u were explained me very well. The problem is now solved. :)

Comment: @Pink great! what was it in the end that you did differently?

Comment: @dovogotland- The script above is working fine, but I have a little issue. I used form action to direct my page to another page, the issue is the page gets directed without executing rest of the script. New file is not created everytime, it gets created when I leave the action form to blank.

Comment: @Pink if the code i provided as a solution is "working fine", then you should accept the answer. if you have a new problem after that, then you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The form is sending a GET request, but you are trying to access `$_POST["text_box"]`.  Try changing that to `$_GET['text_box']`, or using a form method POST instead.

Comment: I changed it to both "get" and "post" but still could write to the file

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your PHP code with just:

```
if ($_REQUEST) {
    file_put_contents("t.txt", $_REQUEST["text_box"]);
}
```

That will ensure that file only gets overwritten when the form is actually submitted, not also when the form is displayed.

Comment: I tried $_request but it still doesn't write to the text file

Answer (score 0):

Does `$a` have data? Try `echo`'ing it out. Or, try `print_r`'ing your `$_POST`.

**EDIT:** Your form's method is `get`, but you're trying to use `$_POST`. Use `$_GET`, or, `$_REQUEST`.